# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException - Scanner

Tags: java

when scanner scound time in (while loop) main print Exception:

```js
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
 at eg.edu.alexu.csd.ds.linkedList.cs49.Polynomial.main(Polynomial.java:17)
```

in debug code fail in flag = function.swit(new Scanner(System.in).nextInt());
This is code:

```js
public class Polynomial {
 SinglyLinkedList A = new SinglyLinkedList();
 SinglyLinkedList B = new SinglyLinkedList();
 SinglyLinkedList C = new SinglyLinkedList();
 SinglyLinkedList R = new SinglyLinkedList();
 
 public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
  Polynomial function = new Polynomial();
  boolean flag = true;
  while(flag){
   function.menu();
   flag = function.swit(new Scanner(System.in).nextInt());
  }
 }
 public boolean swit(int choose){
  Polynomial function = new Polynomial();
  boolean flag = true;
  switch(choose){
      case 1: function.setSwitch();break;
      case 2: function.printSwitch();break;
      case 3: function.addSwitch();break;
      case 4: function.subtractSwitch();break;
      case 5: function.multiplySwitch();break;
      case 6: function.evaluateSwitch();break;
      case 7: function.clearSwitch();break;
      default : flag = false;
     }
  return flag;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if element exists with [`hasNextInt()`](http://[1]%20:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29)  before to do `nextInt()`

Should be something like this

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int value = 0;
if(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
  value = scanner.nextInt(); 
}
flag = function.swit(value);
```

Comment: thank you ,but this does not work this give me the same Exception

Comment: Please, show how you rewrite your code with hasNextInt(). And my recommendation doesn't try to write all code in one string like this `flag = function.swit(new Scanner(System.in).nextInt())`